# How to use XPath in Ruby to get tag with a specific attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath

For instance, I want to get the value inside this tag

```
<meta charset="euc-kr">
```

in this document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="euc-kr">     
</Head>
</HTML>
```

How do I use XPath in Ruby to get any meta tag that has the attribute "charset"?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby REXML library let's use XPath. Below example shows how to use xpath in your case.

```
require 'rexml/document'

xml = %{<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="euc-kr"></meta>    
    <link charset="en-us"></link> 
</head>
</html>}

 doc = REXML::Document.new xml

 REXML::XPath.match(doc, '//*[@charset]')
```

Result:

```
=> [<meta charset='euc-kr'/>, <link charset='en-us'/>]
```